# Securely Encrypting DynamoDB LastEvaluatedKey For Pagination

Tags: go, encryption, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aes

I am working on generating a secure next token used for pagination based on the last evaluated key from DynamoDB to prevent injection attacks as well as exposing my primary key to malicious users.

Currently, I am base encoding my last evaluated key to get my project rolling, but this approach is not practical and exposes risk from malicious users. I have looked into using AES for encrypting and decrypting my last evaluated key, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

I am looking for feedback from others with more experience on best practices to create secure pagination tokens. Also, I am using a single table design for my database, so my improvement to my base64 next token generation will all be switched to a secure design to mitigate risk.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately up to your own preferences. What I have seen in the past is people using their KMS key to encrypt LEK to return to the client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Encrypt.html

I've also seen users who do not expose the LEK to the client at all, instead caching it on the server side for short periods.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll checkout the KMS key to encrypt the LEK to return to the client, but it seems that AES is working for now. I was worried about performance, but I may be over thinking it with how long the AES encryption takes.

Comment: Using KMS is more about the key management portion of your encryption protocol. In terms of algo, you would still have to choose something and that something would most likely still be some variation of AES and a key derivation algo.